Problemas al realizar migraciones en .NET 8
Buen día a todos.
Como dice el título, tengo problemas para realizar migraciones en .NET8, debido a que he tenido que usar un equipo no tan potente me he visto en la obligación de usar VSCode en lugar de Visual Studio y por lo tanto he tenido que usar los comandos de consola dotnet para hacer cualquier tipo de accion en el proyecto que estoy realizando, mi problema surge cuando trato de ejecutar el comando dotnet-ef database update y me arroja este error

Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'Database')

Este es mi código del DBContext de la aplicación
public class APIStatsContext : DbContext
    {
        public APIStatsContext() {}
        public APIStatsContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

        public DbSet<Federation> Federations { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Association> Associations { get; set; }

        public DbSet<League> Leagues { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Championship> Championships { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }

        public DbSet<OffensiveStat> OffensiveStats { get; set; }

        public DbSet<PitchingStat> PitchingStats { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Sponsor> Sponsors { get; set; }

        public DbSet<FederationTeam> FederationTeams { get; set; }

        public DbSet<AssociationTeam> AssociationTeams { get; set; }

        public DbSet<LeagueTeam> LeagueTeams { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TeamCategory> TeamCategories { get; set; }

        public DbSet<ChampionshipSponsor> ChampionshipSponsors { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySQL();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Association>().HasOne(f => f.Federation).WithMany(a => a.Associations).HasForeignKey(f => f.FederationId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<League>().HasOne(a => a.Association).WithMany(l => l.Leagues).HasForeignKey(a => a.AssociationId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Championship>().HasOne(f => f.Federation).WithMany(c => c.Championships).HasForeignKey(f => f.FederationId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Championship>().HasOne(a => a.Association).WithMany(c => c.Championships).HasForeignKey(a => a.AssociationId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Championship>().HasOne(l => l.League).WithMany(c => c.Championships).HasForeignKey(l => l.LeagueId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Roster>().HasOne(r => r.Championship).WithMany(c => c.Rosters).HasForeignKey(r => r.ChampionshipId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Roster>().HasOne(r => r.Team).WithMany(t => t.Rosters).HasForeignKey(r => r.TeamId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Roster>().HasOne(r => r.Player).WithMany(p => p.Rosters).HasForeignKey(r => r.PlayerId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<OffensiveStat>().HasOne(os => os.Roster).WithMany(r => r.OffensiveStats).HasForeignKey(os => os.RosterId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<PitchingStat>().HasOne(ps => ps.Roster).WithMany(r => r.PitchingStats).HasForeignKey(ps => ps.RosterId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<FederationTeam>().HasKey(ft => new {ft.FederationId, ft.TeamId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<AssociationTeam>().HasKey(at => new {at.AssociationId, at.TeamId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<TeamCategory>().HasKey(tc => new {tc.TeamId, tc.CategoryId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChampionshipSponsor>().HasKey(cs => new {cs.ChampionsipId, cs.SponsorId});
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChampionshipCondition>().HasOne(c => c.Championship).WithMany(c => c.ChampionshipConditions).HasForeignKey(c => c.ChampionshipId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LeagueTeam>().HasKey(lt => new {lt.LeagueId, lt.TeamId});
        }
    } 

He intentado varias cosas que he investigado pero no logro dar con la solucion al problema, incluso he actualizado la version de la herramienta ef pero nada parecer solucionar el problema y lo curioso es que cuando lo ejecuto en Visual Studio todo funciona correctamente.

¿Seguro que el comando tiene un guión?

@fredyfx la verdad es que lo he intentado de todas formas, el error siempre es el mismo. Pero en Visual Studio si me actualiza la base de datos con normalidad, el error me lo arroja es cuando intento ejecutar los comandos en Visual Studio Code.

Vamos por partes:
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration -s .\proyecto.API -p .\proyecto.Persistence -v --context ApplicationDbContext

Ten en mente que la ruta del proyecto luego del -s tiene que estar bien, justo de ese proyecto es de donde se obtiene la cadena de conexión del appsettings.json
dotnet ef database update -s .\proyecto.API -p .\proyecto.Persistence -v --context ApplicationDbContext

Dato muy importante: ese -v sirve para ver todo lo que ocurre desde el lado del Entity Framework, hay ocasiones donde tienen varios DbContext y se les olvida especificar.

funcionó a la perfección, muchísimas gracias, tenía días intentando hacer que las migraciones funcionaran.

¡Un gusto colaborar, sigue progresando! :D
